# $2$-norm of a matrix obtained through discretization of the eigenvalue problem

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-norm, circulant-matrices

Define $$A = \frac{1}{2h} \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & & & & -1\\
 -1 & 0 & 1 & & \\
&\ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
& & & -1 & 0 & 1  \\
1 & & &  & -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d},$$
where $d = \frac{1}{h}$. The task is to show that $\rho(A) = \sqrt{\lambda_{\text{max}}(A^*A)} \ge d$ when $d$ is divisible by $4$. I have a proof, but it is long and tedious, since I am following the definitions. I would like to know if there is a simpler way to approach this problem and if this proof is correct.

My proof:  We first compute $A^*A$, which is given by $$ A^*A = \frac{1}{4h^2}\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & -1 & & & -1 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0 & -1 & & & -1 \\
&\ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
-1 &  &  &  -1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & &  & -1 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$
where the rows of $A^*A$ are cycling over $(-1,0,2,0,-1)$.  Now $A^*A v = \lambda v$ if and only if $-v_{j-2}+2v_j-v_{j+2} = \lambda v_j$, $j=1,\cdots,d$, $v_{-1} = v_{d+1}$, $v_{0} = v_d$, $v_{d+1} = v_{1}$, $v_{d+2} = v_{2}$. Now, I was stuck here for sometime and I guessed that the eigenvectors might be of the form $v_{j} = \sin(jk\theta)$ where $k \in \{ 1,\cdots,d\}$ and $j=1,\cdots,d$. Since $$\begin{align*} -v_{j-2}+2v_j-v_{j+2} &= -\sin((j-2)k\theta)+2\sin(jk\theta)-\sin((j+2)k\theta) \\ 
&= -2\sin(jk\theta) \cos{(2k\theta)}+2\sin(jk\theta)= 4\sin^2(k\theta)v_{j},\end{align*}$$
and $\lambda = 4\sin^2(k\theta)$. Now to satisfy the boundary conditions, I simply took $\theta = 2\pi h$. Thus, $$\rho(A) = \frac{1}{h}\max_{k=1,\dots,d} |\sin{(2\pi h k)}|,$$ and if $d$ is divisible by $4$, then $d = 4d'$ for some integer $d'$ and

$$\rho(A) \ge \frac{1}{h}|\sin{\left(\frac{2\pi}{4d'} d'\right)}| = \frac{1}{h} = d$$

NOTE: The matrix $A$ was obtained through the discretization of the eigenvalue problem $\frac{d}{dx} v = \lambda v$ through the central difference scheme with periodic boundary conditions $v(0) = v(1)$.

Comment: The eigenvalues of circulant matrices should not be hard to compute

Comment: Oh, I am not aware of this. What is the trick here then to compute the eigen vectors.

Comment: The eigenvectors are the columns of the Fourier matrix — think of the FFT https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix

Comment: [Toeplitz and Circulant Matrices](https://ee.stanford.edu/~gray/toeplitz.html)